# git—dangling blob/bad object after .git directory accidently added

Tags: git

today I encounter a strange git thing: I have setup a Project A, in Directory A. I copied another Repository B into that and ran a `git add --all`, committed and pushed, before I have removed `A/B/.git`, because I just forgot it.

So now all changes in `A/B` are ignored by git, trying to see some details of that folder within intellij throws `Bad Object A/B` error and `git fsck` showed something like: `dangling blob …`, what is also gone now, after I used those commands:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Here is a simplified diagram of the directory layout:

```
+A
+.git
++B
 +.git //added by mistake
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this

```
git rm -r --cached .
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

Comment: of course can I try that, but is it possible that I will delete some source code with that?

Comment: will that remove source files, or only affect the git stuff?